# Control SQL Query Values input to Excel cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I wasn't really sure how to word this question, so I provided steps.

Steps: (VBA-Excel)

1. Data gets inserted into the database. A query runs to pull all the companies who has violations and insets them into excel.
2. I then have a loop that takes the value of each company name and insert the cell value (Company name) into another query that retrieves emails.

The problem I have is that some companies have two emails listed. So the db query looks like this:

- Company/Email
- Microsoft/email1@...
- Microsoft/email2@...
- Sony/email@...

When the email query is ran using (hope it helps)

```
n = 1
 Do While IsEmpty(Range("A" & n).Value) <> True 'If Cells in Col A is not empty
     CSCust = Range("A" & n).Value
     qryEmail = "SELECT Email FROM dbo.tblPHEmails WHERE SamplePoint LIKE '" & CSCust & "'"
     Set connect = New ADODB.Connection
     connect.Open (strConnectStr)
     '
     'Clean Stream Query
     Set recordSetCSEmail = New ADODB.recordSet
     recordSetCSEmail.Open qryEmail, connect
     Range("C" & n).CopyFromRecordset recordSetCSEmail
     n = n + 1
 Loop
```

In Excel, this overwrites one email because it automatically inputs the values on the next row where the next company gets checked (replaced by this company's email). I wish to get the data so where it'll be like:

- Company/Email/Email2
- Microsoft/email1@.../email2@...
- Sony/email@...

I know it's a bit long (I apologize), is this possible? Or, should I go and edit the email list in the DB to allow for each company to have more than one email field?

Comment: I would change the sql statement to give you both emails in one line.  With a nested select statement you could return the second email or a null value if none exists.  And before asking; to do this it would require knowing your DB platform and other info.  It would then be a new question.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it worked out great!

Answer (score 0):

try adding the maximum number of rows to be copied, using:

```
Range("C" & n).CopyFromRecordset recordSetCSEmail, 1
```

Comment: This was a good try. Now I just need to figure out how to get that second email into the next column.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution after going over the logic over and over. During the loop, I will just check if a extra email was stored in the cell below (no more than two emails for each company) and move it to the correct location.